# Where is thread data stored, and how does OS pass register-like values to CPU when OS execute other process?

Tags: operating-system

I know process and thread scheduling. I want to know where thread data stored, and how the OS passes register-like values to CPU when OS execute other process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread data is stored in RAM in data structures managed by the OS.

Values in registers need to be copied to RAM when switching to another process and the other process's backed-up register values are copied from RAM back into registers before continuing the execution of the other process. This is called [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

Google "context switch" or "context switching" if you want to read more on this.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

First, I don't speak good English.

So my question seems to be wrong.


Yes, As your say, the register values are backed-up in RAM. I know.

Then, who control(or scheduling) the thread?

Who checks thread's time slice?

Process?

Of course do cpu and menory, but my question is in OS

Comment: That depends on your OS but let's assume a modern OS like Windows after 95, Linux and Mac OS after X. The OS will set up various interrupt handlers for I/O and also a timer interrupt. What triggers the timer and I/O interrupt is hardware - it's simply a circuit that does something when a signal arrives and triggers the CPU interrupt. When an interrupt happens the OS pauses the current process and backs up registers in RAM and check which process is waiting for the event. The OS then wakes up the process waiting for events

Comment: If no I/O events happen then the timer interrupt will at some time get triggered. This will cause the OS to check the process queue to see which process should it run next (by longest paused, by priority etc. -- there are lots of algorithms for this and some OS like LInux allow you to recompile the kernel to use a different algorithm for example RTLinux). This is how a single core/single thread CPU can be shared by multiple processes/threads and how a quad core/8-thread CPU can run thousands of threads

Comment: The OS is basically a bunch of interrupt handlers

Comment: Really thank you.

I learned I/O and time interrupt from you.

Last question, how OS decide execute thread?

like Process scheduling?

And I know thread data stored in PCB, OS decide which thread to run using PCB?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by PCB and I'm not sure what you mean by "decide to execute" but the OS decides to switch threads the way I described above - when it responds to interrupts. If by "decide" you mean how it "runs" threads that's simple. The OS simply restores all register values for the thread including the stack pointer then it simply `returns` to the code location where the process was paused. Because an interrupt act like a function call ending an interrupt also act like returning from a function...

Comment: ... Depending on the CPU architecture this is sometimes a separate return-from-interrupt instruction but sometimes the OS will simply do the normal function return (some CPUs don't even have a return instruction, instead you simply write the return address to the program counter - in which case the OS will do just that)

Comment: I mean "runs". That's right. Thank you very much.